# not recieving a confirmation email with fosuserbundle

Tags: php, symfony

i'm trying to do my first symfony project and i am using the fosuserbundle. It's working perfectly i'm just having a problem with the email confirmation, i'm not receiving anything.

> This is my parameters.yml:

parameters:

```
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: null
    database_name: mydatabase
    database_user: root
    database_password: null
    mailer_transport: smtp
    mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
    mailer_user: mymail@gmail.com
    mailer_password: mypass
    secret: 8c73d1f9bc7f50ce500d4a98a4627ffaa42dc905
```

> this is myconfig.yml:

swiftmailer:

```
transport: %mailer_transport%
host:      %mailer_host%
username:  %mailer_user%
password:  %mailer_password%
port: "585"
spool:     { type: memory }
```

fos_user:

```
db_driver:     orm          
firewall_name: main           
user_class:    OC\UserBundle\Entity\User 
service:
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
registration:
    confirmation:
        enabled:    true
        from_email: 
            address: mymail@gmail.com
            sender_name: myname
 service:
    mailer:  fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
```

please can you help? because i searched on the web and tried but since it's my first project none of the solutions are working with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with these slight changes in your `config.yml`:

```
port: 585
auth_mod: login
```

The value for the port doesn't need to be enclosed in quotes. I'm not sure if this really makes a difference, but you should follow the conventions.

Since you're using `smtp` as `mailer_transport` you have also to specify the authentication mode. Check the documentation for more details:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html

Eventually you'll need another value for the authentication mode.

EDIT (2016-02-19):

Instead of using `smtp` as `mailer_transport` you can use the shortcut `gmail`. Please see this article from the Symfony Cookbook:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/gmail.html

Then you can omit the line:

```
auth_mod: login
```

This shortcut will set the `host` to `smtp.gmail.com`. In your configuration you have the host set to 127.0.0.1. This could eventually be the reason why it works with the `web_profiler`, but not with the real e-mail address.

Comment: thanks cezar for your help but I tried it and it still didn't work!

Comment: if i set the intercept_redirects to true i receive an email in the profiler but when i set to false i don't receive it to the real mail.   Please help

Comment: Thank you cezar for your help! it works! I just have one question whenever i receive an email i get the link but can't click on it, what can be the problem?

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem can be. We lack background information on this issue, so it would be only guessing. Since your initial problem is solved, you can close this thread (select the answer) and start a new thread for your new problem providing more details.

Comment: i'm sorry since it's the first time i post on this site i didn't quite know how its procedure work. I will now and thank you for your help.